# Is it possible to write to a excel file from a batchfile?

Tags: batch-file, xls, xlsx

I have a xls file stored in a network share. 
I want the batch to add new info to it. So in the batch I have %ordernr%, %resp% %start% and %end%. How and is it possible to add text to a xls document? 
 [image: XLS]

Comment: Would a `.csv` file be a possible alternative for you?

Comment: its possible with jscript/vbscript/wsh   - libre office comes with its own com objects and has a neat documentation. Moreover you can combine the jscript/cbscript code in one file with the batch.

Comment: will it be easyer with .csv file? I can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Think i found the solution as i dont need xls. I use csv and edited as follow:

```
@Echo off
Set var1=1
Set var2=2
Set var3=3
echo %var1%, %var2%, %var3%, >> mydatafile.csv
```